# Powershell DataTable displaying headers in the wrong order

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

when i import my csv into my GUI the headers get imported into the wrong order any ideas?

code below

```
#### Load Data Table Into Gridview
$button2_Click = {

$data= Import-CSV "E:\testGui\_stock_processed2.csv" 

$dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable

$columns = $data | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty name | 
$columns | %{
 [void]$dt.columns.add($_)
}
$data | %{
 $currentRow = $_
 
 $dr = $dt.NewRow()
 $columns | %{
  $dr.$_ = $currentRow.$_ 
 }
 $dt.Rows.Add($dr)
}

$DataGridview1.DataSource = $dt
}
```

please see correct `.CSV` headers

[image]

and the output the GUI is showing

[image]

it looks as though on import the headers get put in alphabetical order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-Member` formatted output orders the members by `MemberType` and then by `Name`. If you want the property list based on the input object order, then you can use `PSObject.Properties` sub-property.

```
$data.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {
    [void]$dt.Columns.Add($_.Name)
}
```